# "Unwrap" Optional of Optional.empty before return in a Java stream (or Parallel Stream)

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm having trouble with this simple thing. I have a method returning an `Optional<TypeA>`:

```
public Optional<TypeA> getFirst() {
  return set.stream().filter(it -> it.getStatus() == SUCCESS).findFirst(); // set is a Set<TypeA>
}
```

...then I'm calling it from:

```
public boolean hasFirst() {
  return types.parallelStream() // types is a List<TypeB> that has a Set<TypeA>
    .filter(it -> it.getTotalAmount() > 0)
    .map(TypeA::getFirst)
    .findFirst() // this can return an Optional[Optional.empty]
    .isPresent();
}
```

The issue is that, an `Optional` of an empty `Optional` is returning `true`, as expected, so I have no idea how to get this one right!

Any clues?

Comment: What is `TypeA`? What is `txs`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [`Optional#flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to 'unwrap' the inner optional:

```
public boolean hasFirst() {
   return types.parallelStream()
       .filter(it -> it.getTotalAmount() > 0)
       .map(TypeA::getFirst)
       .findFirst() // return Optional[Optional.empty]
       .flatMap(i -> i) // <---
       .isPresent(); // true
}
```

> If a value is present, apply the provided Optional-bearing mapping function to it, return that result, otherwise return an empty Optional.

Comment: we can convert `flatMap(i -> i)` to `flatMap(Function.identity())`

Answer (score 5):

Using `.findFirst().isPresent()` is a common anti-pattern. If you only want to know whether there is a match, there is no need to ask for the *first* one, *especially*, if you intend to use a parallel Stream, where searching for the first match rather than any match can have significant performance drawbacks. So `findAny` would be preferrable, but it is not necessary to ask for a value at all, when you only want to know, whether there is a match:

```
public boolean hasFirst() {
  return types.parallelStream() // types is a List<TypeB> that has a Set<TypeA>
    .filter(it -> it.getTotalAmount() > 0)
    .anyMatch(obj -> obj.getFirst().isPresent());
}
```

It’s not clear, how your original code is supposed to work, if `types` is a list of `TypeB` instances and `getFirst()` is a method declared in `TypeA`, as `TypeA::getFirst` indicated, however, I think, you get the picture…

I recommend to also rename the method `hasFirst()` to `hasAny()`. Of course, a set having *any* matching element will also have a *first* one, but this focussing on “first” is misleading, especially as the `TypeA` elements are in a `Set`, which usually implies that there is no defined order at all.

Answer (score 4):

To collapse an `Optional<Optional<Foo>>` into an `Optional<Foo>`, you can use `orElse`, as such:

```
Optional<Optional<Integer>> opt = Optional.of(Optional.empty()); // Your case
Optional<Integer> collapsedOpt = opt.orElse(Optional.empty()); // Will be empty if original is empty or Optional.of(empty).
```

Thus for your example, you can add .orElse to your stream call:

```
public boolean hasFirst() {
  return types.parallelStream()
    .filter(it -> it.getTotalAmount() > 0)
    .map(TypeA::getFirst)
    .findFirst() // return Optional[Optional.empty]
    .orElse(Optional.empty()) // Now Optional.empty if was originally empty
    .isPresent(); // true
}
```